# Check if ID is selected with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Good Day.

I am using the following click function with jQuery

```
 $(function () {

            $("#areas ul a").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#areas ul li a").removeClass('activeAreas');
                $(this).addClass('activeAreas');
                $(".hidden").hide(200);
                $($(this).attr("href")).show(500)

            });

        });
```

What what I would like to do is in that loop, to check whether a specific element is active, then act upon that:

Eg.

```
 $("#areas ul a").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#areas ul li a").removeClass('activeAreas');
                $(this).addClass('activeAreas');
                $(".hidden").hide(200);
                $($(this).attr("href")).show(500)

                //I'm adding this... but it is not working

                if($(this).attr(href) = 'pretoriaDetail'){
                  alert('it works');
                }

            });
```

How do I get that if statement to work...?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by active?

Comment: I assume the `=` in your sample is a typo. It should be `==`. And the href in the if condition should be "href". The code works for me in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Qr5nL/

Comment: `if ( $.trim( $(this).attr(href) ) == '#pretoriaDetail' ) alert('ok');`

Comment: @adeneo also href must be in quotation mark..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if `class` is applied to DOM then `.hasClass` will help.

**Official Document** : http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

and one more thing there is error in your code.

```
if($(this).attr(href) = 'pretoriaDetail'){
          alert('it works');
}
```

must be

```
if($(this).attr("href") == 'pretoriaDetail'){
          alert('it works');
}
```

because what `=` do is assigning value to that while `==` compare it and href must surround in quotation.

Comment: Not just `=` in your code `href` should also be in quotes like this: `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: @jai its okay bro +2 for you too

Comment: thank you. yeah I see that I made a big mistake there...I forgot that = is assigning and == is verifying...thank you for your answer...

Comment: @DavidVanStaden always welcome brother..now see your question don't have down vote....+1 from me

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function () {
        $("#areas ul a").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if(!$(this).hasClass('activeAreas')){
                $("#areas ul li a").removeClass('activeAreas');
                $(this).addClass('activeAreas');
                $(".hidden").hide(200);
                $($(this).attr("href")).show(500);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
var ID = $(this).attr("href");

$('#'+ID).show(500);
```

`Declare a variable and use it as an id.`

Then this should be something like this:

```
      $(function () {
        $("#areas ul a").click(function (event) {
            var ID = $(this).attr("href");
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#areas ul li a").removeClass('activeAreas');
            $(this).addClass('activeAreas');
            $(".hidden").hide(200);
            $('#'+ID).show(500); // or this way $('[id="'+ID+'"]').show(500);
        });
     });
```